# Is it possible to support custom extension file?

Tags: android, android-sharing

If we have a file with a custom extension like **.abc**, can I open this file with the app?

How can we show our app under the suggestion list in **"open with"** options?

Comment: While you are welcome to add an `<intent-filter>` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59089742/115145), this will only work in a small percentage of cases. I recommend that you focus primarily on other ways of letting the user choose the content, such as using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity ...>
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <data android:scheme="file"  
          android:host="*" 
          android:pathPattern=".*\\.abc" 
          android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

More to read: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.

Comment: Note that the `file` `Uri` scheme was largely banned in Android 7.0. `content` is much more common, and `content` `Uri` values do not have to have a file extension.

Comment: @Yang Liu -thanks. I have tired of your suggestion but it's not working. also tried more ways. Actually I am exporting the file from my app like 
 `emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
 emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
 emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, apkURI);` with custom extension. But not able to support my app with same file for importing. am I missing anyting?